# Uninstall Excel Add-in Invantive Control - Exact Online Edition

Tags: invantive-control

I've installed the Invantive Control Excel add-in for Exact Online using Microsoft ClickOnce by running setup.exe.

How can I uninstall it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can uninstall Invantive Control by:

- Going to Programs & Features,
- Select 'Invantive Control' and
- Choose 'Uninstall' button.

Despite Invantive Control being an Exact Online add-in to Excel, it is also available as a program for de-installation.

## Update

The ClickOnce installation was replaced by an MSI installer, but the procedure remains the same. Note however that ClickOnce is typically a per-user install, whereas MSI is typically a systemwide installation.